# Request to rename [amchart] tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I am not affiliated in any way with the makers of [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com/), the JavaScript/Flex charting tool. That being said, I think it makes sense to change the name of the tag, which is currently [amchart](/questions/tagged/amchart), to what seems to me the proper name: [amcharts](/questions/tagged/amcharts). After all "amCharts" is the name of the product on their [website](http://www.amcharts.com/), and `AmCharts` is their javascript namespace.

Just like no one would want to see the [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) product tagged as [highchart](/questions/tagged/highchart), the [amchart](/questions/tagged/amchart) tag should be [amcharts](/questions/tagged/amcharts).